# Передача файлов и текстовых данных Java

Tags: java, ajax, servlet, fileupload

Подскажите пожалуйста. Сделал загрузку файла при помощи AJAX, плагином для JQuery. Появилась нужда передача значения при загрузке файла. Под значением я имею в виду скрытый input в котором будет значение. Сервер написан на Java - то бишь загружаю файл через Servlet. Загрузка только файлов есть.

Comment: А что подсказать-то?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev как такое сделать?

Comment: Покажите код, которые есть.